# 'You must enable Javascript to view this page properly' error in shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

I was trying to use rgl plot in shiny,but somehow it is throwing error:

> 'You must enable Javascript to view this page properly'.

Javascript is already enabled. I used '**shinyRGL**' library in R to display its output,but failed.

Kindly help!

Comment: What version of rgl?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug with shinyRGL 0.95.1247. Here is the [thread](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyRGL/issues/10) on GitHub started May 4th, 2015. In sum, previous versions of shinyRGL worked properly, but the upgrade to 0.95.1247 causes this error to be reported in FireFox, and a similar error in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I even tried installing older packages,but it also failed. I have 0.95.1247 version of rgl package and struggling to get the crack. Help please.

Comment: In light of that information, can you post some of your code for us?

Comment: #ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(strong('Executive Path Finder')),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
   ),
  mainPanel(
    
    webGLOutput ('NetDiag')))))

#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$NetDiag  <- renderWebGL({
    J=path(input$Person1,input$Person2,input$Degree)
    
    g<-graph.data.frame(J)
    coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g, dim=3)
    V(g)[V(g)$name == input$Person1]$color <- "green"
rglplot(g,layout=coords,vertex.label.dist=0.25,vertex.label.font=0.2,vertex.label.color='black',vertex.label.cex=.6,edge.arrow.size=0)
    
  })
  
})

Comment: I got the same error MSG when I run an shinyRGL example. Does anybody know how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Quick update, the package maintainer Jeff Allen postet a fix in the README.MD: 
Install a working RGL version clone from his github via devtools:
`install_github("rgl", "trestletech", "js-class")`
(Make sure you do this in a fresh R session with rgl unloaded or even better, already removed from your library)